# How to attach an "handler" to a PopupMenu inside a Manipulate, using the second argument of Dynamic, when the item list is itself variable

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I have some trouble evolving from this

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{"date: ", date}, {"dates: ", dates}}],

 {{dates, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"}}, None},
 {{date, 1}, dates, PopupMenu},
 Button["Add", 
  AppendTo[dates, 
   dates[[-1, 1]] + 1 -> 
    FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[dates[[-1, 2]]] + 1]]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I whish to attach an "handler" so that when i change the PopupMenu I can do something. I tried this

```
Manipulate[
 If[updated,
  Print["updated"];
  updated = False
  ];
 Grid[{{"date: ", date}, {"dates: ", dates}}],

 {{dates, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"}}, None},
 {{updated, False}, None},

 {{date, 1}, dates, 
  PopupMenu[Append[#, (date = #; updated = True) &], #2[[1]]] &},
 Button["Add", 
  AppendTo[dates, 
   dates[[-1, 1]] + 1 -> 
    FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[dates[[-1, 2]]] + 1]]]
 ]
```

but the `PopupMenu` is not displayed.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following code display the `PopupMenu` but it's not linked to the variable.

```
Manipulate[
 If[updated,
  Print["updated"];
  updated = False
  ];
 Grid[{{"date: ", date}, {"dates: ", dates}}],

 {{dates, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"}}, None},
 {{updated, False}, None},

 {{date, 1}, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"}, 
  PopupMenu[Append[#, (date = #; updated = True) &], #2[[1]]] &},
 Button["Add", 
  AppendTo[dates, 
   dates[[-1, 1]] + 1 -> 
    FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[dates[[-1, 2]]] + 1]]]
 ]
```

If possible I whish to use Manipulate and declare the local variable `date` and consume it at the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some "magic" happens transparently when the items list is dynamic so the first

```
{{date, 1}, dates, PopupMenu}
```

is not equivalent to

```
{{date, 1}, dates, PopupMenu[#, #2[[1]]]&}
```

but to

```
{{date, 1}, dates, Dynamic@PopupMenu[#, #2[[1,1]]]&}
```

when `#2[[1]]` is a `_Dynamic` as in this case.

Si I found this way:

```
Manipulate[
 If[updated,
  Print["updated"];
  updated = False
  ];
 Grid[{{"date: ", date}, {"dates: ", dates}}],

 {{dates, {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"}}, None},
 {{updated, False}, None},

 {{date, 1}, dates, 
  Dynamic@PopupMenu[
     Append[#, (date = #; updated = True) &], #2[[1, 1]]] &},
 Button["Add", 
  AppendTo[dates, 
   dates[[-1, 1]] + 1 -> 
    FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[dates[[-1, 2]]] + 1]]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maybe obvious, and/or already discussed, but I haven't found anything related. Hope someone find it useful.